# multiple notifications in a foreground worker

Tags: android, worker, android-workmanager, foregroundnotification

I am using a worker manager to upload videos along with a notification. When the user tries to upload a video again with an ongoing upload worker job the notification for the second upload is not shown even though the work is being executed. I am using a unique notification Id and calling setForegroundAsync as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running). I would like to have notification shown for every video upload work submitted.

P.S Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks

```
public class PostUploadWorker extends Worker {


    private PostDao postDao;

    private AppPref appPref;

    private HttpLoggingInterceptor logging;

    private PostEntity postEntity;

    private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;

    private Bitmap videoThumbnail = null;

    public PostUploadWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams, @NonNull HttpLoggingInterceptor logging, @NonNull AppPref appPref,
                            @NonNull PostDao postDao) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        this.logging = logging;
        this.appPref = appPref;
        this.postDao = postDao;
        this.notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        // Inject fields
        long postId = getInputData().getLong(Constants.INTENT_POST_ID, -1);

        // upload post
        if (postId != -1) {
            postEntity = postDao.getPost(postId);
            File videoFile = new File(postEntity.getStoragePath());
            if (postEntity.getStoragePath() != null && videoFile.exists()) {
                if (postEntity != null && !(postEntity.getPostStatus().equals(PostStatus.PROCESSING) || postEntity.getPostStatus().equals(PostStatus.COMPLETED))) {
                    try {
                        setForegroundAsync(createForegroundInfo(true, (int) postId));
                        // upload call
                        Call<VideoUploadResponse> uploadVideo = initRetrofit().uploadVideo(appPref.getAuth().typedToken(), body, map);
                        try {
                            Response<VideoUploadResponse> response = uploadVideo.execute();
                            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                                VideoUploadResponse vidUploadResponse = response.body();
                                deleteLogFile(postId);
                                postEntity.setPostStatus(PostStatus.PROCESSING);
                                postEntity.setEventId(vidUploadResponse.getEventId());
                                postDao.updatePost(postEntity);
                                trackPost("worker upload completed", postEntity);
                                setForegroundAsync(createForegroundInfo(false, (int) postId));
                            } else {
                                App.reportError(appPref.getAuth().getUserId(), "uploadVideo", response.code(), uploadVideo.request());
                                // TODO retry
                                trackPost("upload worker failed with response code " + response.code() + ";\n" + uploadVideo.request().toString(), postEntity);
                                return handlePostUploadFailure(postEntity);
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO retry
                            App.reportError(appPref.getAuth().getUserId(), "", null, uploadVideo.request(), e.fillInStackTrace());
                            Log.e("PostUploadWorker", "Upload Failed with post id: " + postEntity.getId());
                            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
                            e.printStackTrace(pw);
                            trackPost("upload worker failed with trace " + ";\n" + sw.toString(), postEntity);
                            return handlePostUploadFailure(postEntity);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        App.reportError(appPref.getAuth().getUserId(), "uploadWorker", null, null, e.fillInStackTrace());
                        Log.e("PostUploadWorker", "Upload Failed with post id: " + postEntity.getId());
                        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
                        e.printStackTrace(pw);
                        trackPost("upload worker failed with trace " + ";\n" + sw.toString(), postEntity);
                        return handlePostUploadFailure(postEntity);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                postEntity.setPostStatus(PostStatus.UPLOADING_FAILED);
                postDao.updatePost(postEntity);
                trackPost("upload worker failed. File to upload doesn't exist", postEntity);
                return Result.success();
            }
        }
        // Indicate whether the work finished successfully with the Result
        if (videoThumbnail != null) videoThumbnail.recycle();

        return Result.success();
    }

    @NonNull
    private ForegroundInfo createForegroundInfo(boolean isUnderProgress, int notificationId) {
        // Build a notification using bytesRead and contentLength

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String id = context.getString(R.string.uploads_notification_channel_id);
        String title = context.getString(R.string.uploads_notification_title);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createChannel();
        }

        if (videoThumbnail == null && postEntity != null) {
            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    videoThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(new File(postEntity.getStoragePath()), new Size(200, 200), new CancellationSignal());
                } else {
                    videoThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(postEntity.getStoragePath(), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, id)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setTicker(title);
        if (videoThumbnail != null) {
            notification.setLargeIcon(videoThumbnail);
        }
        if (postEntity != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(postEntity.getTitle())) {
            notification.setContentText(postEntity.getTitle());
            notification.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(postEntity.getTitle()));
        }

        if (isUnderProgress) {
            notification.setProgress(0,0, true);
            notification.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
            notification.setOngoing(true);
        } else {
            notification.setProgress(0,0, false);
            notification.setContentTitle("video posted");
            notification.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN);
            notification.setOngoing(false);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", notificationId);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), notificationId, intent, 0);

        Notification notification1 = notification
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo_remush)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();


        return new ForegroundInfo(notificationId, notification1, 1);
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void createChannel() {
        // Create a Notification channel
        CharSequence name = "post uploads";
        String description = "post uploads";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("uploads", name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    private Result handlePostUploadFailure(PostEntity postEntity) {
        // retry until 5 tries reached
        if (postEntity.getUploadRetry() <= 5) {
            postEntity.setUploadRetry(postEntity.getUploadRetry() + 1);
            postDao.updatePost(postEntity);
            return Result.retry();
        } else {
            // update failed status
            postEntity.setPostStatus(PostStatus.UPLOADING_FAILED);
            postDao.updatePost(postEntity);
            return Result.failure();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {
        if (postEntity != null) trackPost("upload worker stopped", postEntity);
        if (videoThumbnail != null) videoThumbnail.recycle();
        super.onStopped();
    }

}
```

```
        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build();

        WorkRequest postWorkRequest =
                new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(PostUploadWorker.class)
                        .setInputData(new Data.Builder()
                                .putLong(Constants.INTENT_POST_ID, postEntity.getId())
                                .build())
                        .setConstraints(constraints)
                        .addTag("vid_upload_" + postEntity.getId())
                        .setBackoffCriteria(
                                BackoffPolicy.LINEAR,
                                10L,
                                TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build();
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this? I'm seeing the same issue.